# Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-slick'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
import Slider from "react-slick";
```

i have imported react slick also installed it.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef,useState } from 'react';
import Slider from "react-slick";
import '../Styles/Work.css' ;
const Work = () => {
  
  return (
    <div style={{height:"100vh"}} ref={ref} className='work-container' id="work">
      <h1 ref={title} className='work-title'>
        MY WORKS
      {/* {inView && navigate('/#about')}   */}
      </h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Work
```

**`packagelock`  file**

```
"react-scripts": "5.0.0",
"react-slick": "^0.28.1",
"react-slick-carousel": "^0.14.9",
```

it's displays in my `package-lock`  too. what's the issue here?? i am using react with typescript

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to install the types for 'react-slick'  `@types/react-slick` . Make sure its on your package.json as well as r@types/react
16.8.2

@types/react-dom

Comment: its not reading the css imports aswell. do you know whats the issue there?

Comment: seems correct for me, make sure that the classes have a dot like '.work-container'  and the path is ok, try placing the css file  on the same folder might help for debug

Answer (score 6):

As you use typescript, you have to install it's type by following:

```
npm install --save @types/react-slick
```